# Can the WHERE conditions affect specific columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, where-clause

I am creating a procedure and have encountered the following problem. (I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008)

I have one table which contained data spread over a month (let's say from the 1st to the 30th).  Each day of the month contains the same amount of data (so each day of the month has the same number of rows in the table).  I would like to have one column with the data of pertaining to the start date and one with the data from the end date (I don't want the data in between to be shown).

I have tried using JOIN like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE afficherConsomPools @start Date, @end Date

SELECT dateCollecte, pool, capacityInKB, freeCapacityInKB, 
       endUsedCapacityInKB = capacityInKB - freeCapacityInKB
FROM Vsp_Pool
WHERE dateCollecte = @end
JOIN
SELECT startUsedCapacityInKB = capacityInKB - freeCapacityInKB
FROM Vsp_Pool
WHERE dateCollecte = @start
```

But this didn't worked (I don't think we can have a JOIN statement after the WHERE).

I tried using CASE too but I don't think it's what I need here.  What I'm looking for is a way to apply the condition in the WHERE to different columns (instead of all of them).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That will not work, you need to read up on basic SQL syntax. Explain more about the data and teh expected results and may be we can point you in the right direction, but I don't understnd at all what you are tyring to accomplish.

Comment: As far as I know, the JOIN command is only a part of FROM clausel.

Comment: From my understanding UNION adds rows and I'm looking for a column.  That being said I will try to make it clearer thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE afficherConsomPools (
    @start Date, 
    @end Date)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT 
        [pool], 
        MAX(CASE WHEN dateCollected = @start THEN capacityInKB - freeCapacityInKB ELSE 0 END) AS startUsedCapacityInKB,
        MAX(CASE WHEN dateCollected = @end THEN capacityInKB - freeCapacityInKB ELSE 0 END) AS endUsedCapacityInKB
    FROM 
        Vsp_Pool
    WHERE 
        dateCollected  IN (@end, @start)
    GROUP BY
        [pool]; 
END;
```

Comment: this works perfectly!! Thank you and thanks everyone for the time and help!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to skip all rows in the "middle" of a month and take only the first and last?

One way, you could use a CTE which selects all + two additional columns for the `ROW_NUMBER` of each month. One for ascending order and one for descending. Then you can filter the main query by rows which either have `MonthOrderAsc = 1` or `MonthOrderDesc = 1`.

For example:

```
WITH MonthData 
     AS (SELECT Datecollecte, 
                Pool, 
                Capacityinkb, 
                Freecapacityinkb, 
                EndUsedCapacityInKB = Capacityinkb - Freecapacityinkb, 
                MonthOrderAsc = Row_number() OVER ( 
                            PARTITION BY Year(Datecollecte), Month(Datecollecte) 
                            ORDER BY Datecollecte ASC), 
                MonthOrderDesc = Row_number() OVER ( 
                            PARTITION BY Year(Datecollecte), Month(Datecollecte) 
                            ORDER BY Datecollecte DESC) 
         FROM   Vsp_Pool 
         WHERE  Datecollecte >= @start AND Datecollecte <= @end) 
SELECT * 
FROM   MonthData
WHERE  MonthOrderAsc = 1 OR MonthOrderDesc = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.dateCollecte
    ,a.pool
    ,a.capacityInKB
    ,a.freeCapacityInKB
    ,a.endUsedCapacityInKB = capacityInKB - freeCapacityInKB
    ,b.startUsedCapacityInKB
FROM Vsp_Pool a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT pool
        ,startUsedCapacityInKB = capacityInKB - freeCapacityInKB
    FROM Vsp_Pool
    WHERE dateCollecte = @start
    ) B
    ON a.pool = b.pool
WHERE dateCollecte = @end
```

If i read the question correctly, you are looking to append the starting usage as the last column, this should do it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have data of the form:

```
(Date, PoolId, Value)
```

Where each Date value always has exactly N rows with the same (or different?) PoolIds. The desired result set is a pivot of the data so you have 2 columns corresponding to 2 different dates, with N rows corresponding to the values from each pool for those dates.

The syntax for a pivot query to accomplish this would be something like:

```
SELECT PoolId, [Date1], [Date2]
FROM (SELECT Date, PoolId, Value FROM YourTable) x
PIVOT (SUM(Value) FOR Date IN ([Date1], [Date2]) pvt
```

Where `Date1` and `Date2` are literally the date strings for the two particular dates, and the aggregate `SUM` or `AVG` etc., is used in case a date has two records with the same `PoolId`.